# Installing Node fs module in a react app or otherwise create dir listing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm building a JSON editor in React and it looks like the Node fs module is the way to go if I want to create a directory listing.

I feel dumb but I don't know how to install fs in the app. Do I need to install the entire Node.js inside the app to use the 'fs' module? Is there a stand-alone "fs" library that does the same thing?

Here's the code I want to use. I tried `yarn add fs` and was not surprised that I got `rs.readdir is not a function`.

```
const testFolder = "/";
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you say "app," do you mean *web* app? As in, it runs in a browser? If so, you can't interact with the file system at all (other than `input type="file"` and some limited drag-and-drop actions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React runs in the browser. The Node.js `fs` module cannot run in the browser.

The browser does not provide access to the user's file system (except in very limited ways, such as through `<input type="file">`). You cannot present a directory listing of the system the browser is running on from a webpage.

If you want to present a directory listing of the server's file system, then write a web service and interact with it via Ajax.

(Or use something like Electron if you want a stand-alone application and not a web app).